# Stripe and webpack in symfony

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, stripe-payments

I am trying to use stripe in my symfony 4.4 app, but for some reason it can't work when using *encore_entry_link_tags*.

Everything is ok when using it in my base template

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

But when I use lines below it doesn't work

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

There is nothing in my logs displaying an error.
It seems that when I import bootstrap the fields are not generated, even if I use bootstrap with CDN.

Many thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the solution... It's only CSS breaked with bootstrap.

```
.form-row {
    display: inherit;
}
```